# How to grep line ONLY before and above of my line?

Tags: bash, grep

How to grep lines only one or two before and above of my line, I use

```
 grep --color=always -Irn -E 'foo|bar'
```

but it finds me lines through all document:

```
foo.md:10:foo
foo.md:142:bar
```

I need only a coincidence of NEARBY lines, one or maybe two.

```
foo.md:10:foo
foo.md:12:bar
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find for several hours, but as always it was so simple:

```
grep --color=always -Irn 'foo' -A1 -B1 | grep -In --color=always "bar" -A2 -B1
```

Finding 'foo' and 1 line after '-A1' and 1 line before '-B1', pass this to second grep and process with keyword 'bar' and voilà!
-I is for ignoring binaries, -r means recursive search and -n means output line number.
--color=always - highlights matched string.

Comment: -i is usually ignore case (lower case i). Also note -C1 is equivalent to -A1 -B1

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Edited, -I mean ignoring binaries of course

Answer (score 0):

Get the context lines with the first grep, then filter out the match lines with a second:

```
grep -C 1 'foo' | grep -v 'foo'
```